# Creating a new time-format column from a dask dataframe integer column

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, time, dask

I have dask dataframe with one column named "hora" of integer type, and I want to create other column in time format. I show in the next example:

- my data is:

```
hora
10
17
22
19
14
```

- the result that I hope get for the first row is:

```
hora time 
10   10:00:00
```

for that I am triying:

```
meta = ('time', 'datetime64[ns]')
df['hora'].map_partitions(dt.time, meta=meta).compute()
```

When I run code above throws:

`TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`

However I test the same example with series pandas and works.

[image]

I am applying the function "dt.time" the sameway in both cases, what is it the error?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Please include code, not images, and provide all the imports you are relying on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By passing `dt.time` to `map_partition`, you are effectively doing `dt.time(df)` for each part of your dataframe. What you wanted was to apply the function to each value. You could have done either of the following:

```
ddf.assign(s2=ddf.hora.map(dt.time))
```

or

```
def mapper(df):
    df['s2'] = df.hora.apply(dt.time)
    return df

ddf.map_partitions(mapper)
```

(providing dtype is optional)

Comment: Thanks very much mdurant. I was interpreting it bad I thought that map_partitions operated with series, that was my mistake.